# Django Api: Como criar uma view que faz reset Password?

Tags: django

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação móvel usando a framework Ionic. Existe também uma API em django que comunica com uma Base de Dados PostgreSQL.

Já criei um sistema de autenticação para a aplicação e funciona perfeitamente assim como editar os dados de um utilizador. A minha dúvida é na parte de mudar a password de um User.

Já procurei na internet por formas de resolver este problema mas encontro sempre a implementação com o package django.contrib.auth. O problema é que em todas as formas de resolver este problema, utilizam os forms para uma aplicação web.
No meu caso, apenas queria ter a view para poder realizar um pedido onde mudava a password.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O método [`make_random_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password) do `BaseUserManager` pode ser usado para criar novas senhas aleatórias, especificando-se o tamanho (padrão: 10) e o alfabeto (padrão: alfanumérico, maiúsculas e minúsculas, só ignorando alguns caracteres parecidos).

Sendo assim, tudo que sua view precisa fazer é obter uma instância do `User` certo, chamar o [`set_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) desse usuário com a senha aleatória criada (o próprio método se encarrega de hasheá-la) e então salvá-lo. Exemplo:

```
def resetar_senha(request):
    usuario = User.objects.get(username=request.POST["username"])
    usuario.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
    usuario.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("url/de/sucesso")
```

Comment: Obrigado! Eu de qualquer das maneiras já encontrei um package que tem algumas funcionalidades e ajuda bastante na Autenticação.

https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser